# Clarification on J Increment Behavior When Reaching Zero ( c programming language)

Tags: c

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am seeking an explanation for a specific behavior I have observed in my code. I've noticed that the variable j starts to increment once it reaches the value of 0. Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this behavior? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the code :

```
int main(void)
{
    int j = 2;
    int i = 2;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("initial i : %d ---------- \n", i);
        printf("initial j : %d ---------- \n", j);
        while(i--) {
           j--; 
        }
        printf("the second i : %d ---------- \n", i);
        printf("the second j : %d ---------- \n", j);
        printf("----------------------------------\n");
           
    }
}
```

first it starts decrementing the i and j until i reaches 0 and
that's right because  the `while (i--)` considered false when it attempt to the 0 value but the problem is that it still enter the while with the value -1 and start incrementing the value of j from the last value 0 and then 1, 2, ....

here is the output :

````
initial i : 2 ---------- 
initial j : 2 ---------- 
the second i : -1 ---------- 
the second j : 0 ---------- 
----------------------------------
initial i : -1 ---------- 
initial j : 0 ---------- 





the second i : -1 ---------- 
the second j : 1 ---------- 
----------------------------------
initial i : -1 ---------- 
initial j : 1 ---------- 









the second i : -1 ---------- 
the second j : 2 ---------- 
----------------------------------
initial i : -1 ---------- 
initial j : 2 ---------- 







the second i : -1 ---------- 
the second j : 3 ---------- 
----------------------------------
initial i : -1 ---------- 
initial j : 3 ---------- ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `i--` returns the *old* value of `i`, before you decrement it.

If we unroll the inner loop then it will start like this:

```
// i == 2
j--;
i--;

// i == 1
j--;
i--;

// i == 0
// No loop
i--;
```

Note that `i` is still decremented! So when the inner loop ends, the value of `i` will be equal to `-1`.

Then the iteration of the outer loop happens, which `i == -1`. And since `i` is non-zero you will get an infinite loop with `while (i--)`, where `i` is continuously decremented until it gets to the limit of what an `int` can handle. Then you will get an arighmetic underflow which in turn leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but it seems like you may have misunderstood my question. I'm actually looking for information on the behavior of 'j' specifically after it reaches 0. Could you please provide more insight on that?

Comment: @OTH-KSM Well the value of `j` will be modified (and also reach the arithmetic underflow) inside the (theoretically) infinite inner loop. What really happens is that the value of `i` underflows and becomes very large, then it's decremented until it *again* reaches `0`. By then `j` will have done the same thing and again reached the value `1`.

Comment: @bibo You are asking why it is incremented. That is not true. Both variables are decremented. But `j` is decremented one time less than `i`. That means after an underflow `i` goes all the way down to 0 again while `j` does one step less.